About the projection of a variety from a generic plane being birational
Take $Z\subseteq \mathbb P^N$ an irreducible subvariety of dimension $m$. For $\Lambda$ a projective subspace of dimension $N-m-2$ not intersecting $Z$, define $$\rho_\Lambda:Z\rightarrow\mathbb G(N-m-1,N)$$
which maps $x$ to the subspace spanned by $x$ and $\Lambda$.
From reading papers by Salberger, Heath-Brown and Browning using this, it is my understanding that for any such $\Lambda$, the image of this map should always have dimension $m$. My question is, if that’s even true, why is this the case ?
(For context this is where I need this fact :
I have a proof showing that for any $\Lambda$, the set $S_\Lambda$ of the $M\in \mathbb G(N-m-1,N)$ such that $\Lambda\subseteq M$ and   $\vert M\cap Z\vert >1$ is an algebraic set.
Further, I know that the set of $\Lambda$, such that $\dim S_\Lambda<m$, is dense and open in $\mathbb G(N-m-2,N)$.
Therefore what I’m asking about would give me a proof that for generic $\Lambda$, the map $\rho_\Lambda$ is birational onto its image, because on the complementary of $S_\Lambda$ one can define an inverse rational map $\rho_\Lambda^{-1}$.)
No paper I have read gives any reference for it except for Harris’ Algebraic Geometry [Exercise 11.23] however he does not appear to mention this. Any help is appreciated.

for $M \in G(N-m-2,N)$, the fiber is  $(\mathbb{P}(M) - \mathbb{P}(\Lambda)) \cap Z$... but $\mathbb{P}(M) - \mathbb{P}(\Lambda)$ is affine since $\mathbb{P}(\Lambda) \subset \mathbb{P}(M)$ is a hyperplane in the latter ... does this make sense... now this intersection thus has to be finite... thus $\rho_{\Lambda}$ has finite fibers... it follows that it is finite map, since $Z$ is projective...hence the image has same dimension as $Z$.

Finite maps have finite fibers, however I wasn’t aware the converse was true for maps from projective. Could you provide a reference for this ? I had tried to show that $\rho_\Lambda$ was finite, but I couldn’t prove it…

Here is a reference on MSE which contains pointers to EGA and Stacks: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289772/references-for-quasi-finite-and-proper-implies-finite . If this is enough to resolve your question, please let me know and I can mark it as a duplicate of that.

That is enough, thank you !
